# Fetch API call in Codepen vs. Postman

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm attempting to collect some data from the Last.fm API. Using Postman, and with the call below, I am getting a response.

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9

When I try to achieve the same result on Codepen, I don't get a response. This is the code I'm using:

```js
fetch("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Usually is due to API not being CORS enabled. Any CORS warnings in browser dev tools console. Add a `catch()` also and not error returned

Comment: Don't know much about fetch, but the response in your example is XML and not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both of the commenters mentioned

- CORS issue: you can append `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`(hacky work around)
- specify the data type to be json...

Try this it should work:

```
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&api_key=4a9f5581a9cdf20a699f540ac52a95c9')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Note: You should not share that API key...

Comment: At first instance I tried to access the json data, but that did not work. The herokuapp workaround did work, thanks for that. The API key I got from a tutorial.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm not sure if this is in fact a CORS issue, or was it just the response format issue. If I try the code that the OP include in the question from the browser (using the developer tools) it work just fine, not sure if this hack is really necessary. Good answer though +1